# @FindBy error With class Select

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to implement Page Object with annotation `@FindBy` in class `Select`. In Eclipse it's showing following a message:

> the method id(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement).

I do not why this message comes. Follow below the code and image of error.

[image]

Class **FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage**

```
public class FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id = "cboMotivo")
    WebElement CBOMotivo;
    public FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void preencherCampoMotivo(String CampoMotivo) {
        // Campo Motivo
        WebElement campoMotivo = driver.findElement(By.id(CBOMotivo));
        Select slcMotivo = new Select(campoMotivo);
        slcMotivo.selectByVisibleText(CampoMotivo);
    }
    public void preencherCampoSubmotivo(String CampoSubMotivo) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Class **FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest**

```
public class FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest {
    static WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        SelecionarNavegador nav = new SelecionarNavegador();
        driver = nav.iniciarNavegador("chrome", "http://10.5.9.45/BkoMais_Selenium/");
    }
    @Test
    public void selecionarFacilidades() throws Exception {
        // Logando na aplicação
        LogarBkoMaisPage login = new LogarBkoMaisPage(driver);
        login.logar("844502", "Bcc201707");

        // BackOffice >> FaturamentoGe >> Conectividade
        FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesPage menu = new FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesPage(driver);
        menu.logarFaturamentoGeConectividade();

        //Registro >> Novo caso
        RegistroNovoCasoPage reg = new RegistroNovoCasoPage(driver);
        reg.registrarCaso();

        //Preencher campos
        FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage campo = new FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(driver);
        campo.preencherCampoMotivo(" Concluido ");
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: the CBOMotivo is a WebElement when you define it, you don`t need search again. Only use it. You could comment the line where you are try searching the object by id.

Comment: j.barrio, I commented the line as you said and Eclipse displayed the following error message: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:44)
 at page.FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage.preencherCampoMotivo(FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage.java:24)
 at test.FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest.selecionarFacilidades(FaturamentoGeConectividadeFacilidadesTest.java:38)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `pagefactory.init` to initialize webelement.

```
public FaturamentoGeTratamentoOsPage(WebDriver driver) {    this.driver = driver;
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

No use of below line .. because CBOMotive directly returns you a webelement only

```
WebElement campoMotivo = driver.findElement(By.id(CBOMotivo));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `By.id()` expects a `String`, not a `WebElement`. You have defined `CBOMotivo` as a `WebElement` but are treating it like a `String`.

The following is correct usage

```
WebElement campoMotivo = driver.findElement(By.id("cboMotivo"));
```

What you want is

```
public void preencherCampoMotivo(String CampoMotivo) {
    // Campo Motivo
    Select slcMotivo = new Select(CBOMotivo);
    slcMotivo.selectByVisibleText(CampoMotivo); 
}
```